# Typescript Promise type to show name of returned variable

Tags: typescript, types, promise

I am writing some functions in Typescript for an admin dashboard that will return a promise with a certain value (normally a string).

I am using VS Code and when I hover over the function name when calling it, it shows the type of the returned value (string, number etc).
I want to also display a name along with the type and was wondering what is the best way to do this.

Currently, I am returning an object that has a property with the explicit name and the type next to it.

Example:

Normally, you'd write like this:

```
function normalizeCarMake (carMake: string):Promise<string> {}
```

I write it this way:

```
function normalizeCarMake (carMake: string):Promise<{carMake: string}> {}
```

So that when I hover over the function call in VS Code, it will show:

```
(alias) normalizeCarMakePromise(driverCarMake: string): Promise<{
    carMake: string;
}>
```

It there a better way to achieve this result? I don't want to complicate all the promise returns where just one value is returned.

Comment: I don't think `string` is equivallent to `{carMake: string}`. The first is `string`, the second is `object` that contains property with name `carMake` and is of type `string` itself.

Comment: There is a difference between a sole string and an object containing a string.

Comment: I think in your case, best scenario would be to wrap that `string` in a separate `class` and return that instead of a plain string. That way you would achieve what you want, but this is also good practice from the best coding standards

Comment: What I mean by wrapping `string` in a `class` is basically doing this: `export class CarMake { constructor(public carMake: string) {} }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to just use `string` at runtime instead of an object containing a `string`, but you want something like `carMake` to exist at compile time.  One idea would be to use a type alias:

```
type CarMake = string;
function normalizeCarMake(carMake: CarMake): Promise<CarMake> { ... }
```

Unfortunately, when you hover over `normalizeCarMake`, it will just de-reference that alias and show you

```
function normalizeCarMake(carMake: string): Promise<string>
```

One way around that is to make the alias a little more complicated:

```
type CarMake = string & {__type?: 'CarMake'};
```

which will still accept `string` values; `CarMake` is just `string` at runtime:

```
const toyota: CarMake = 'Toyota';
```

and now if you hover over the function you get

```
function normalizeCarMake(carMake: CarMake): Promise<CarMake>
```

which is maybe what you wanted!  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I might just do that. Is it a problem, though, that I'm returning an object every time instead of just returning a string?

Comment: Returning an object of type `{carMake: string}` is not a problem, if that's what you want to do.  As you noted, it adds a bit of complication... at runtime you have to wrap and unwrap an object when all you care about is a `string`.  But there's nothing really wrong with that.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for sharing this trick. Is it documented feature or you found it a gut of typescript?

Comment: I think it's documented [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal)